# How do I remove Session variable value on redirect to another page

Tags: c#, asp.net, session-variables

I am using a Session["filter"] variable to store the value of a selected dropdown value when a page redirects to itself. But, if any other page is opened then the variable value should be removed. How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

You could use ViewState["filter"] instead which would be specific to that page.

Comment: I am using Response.Redirect due to which the ViewState value is cleared

Answer (score 1):

You could say `Session["filter"]=string.Empty`on the landing page if the page Redirect page is on the same web site/application.

If it is not then you can clear the session variable  using onselectedindexchanged of dropdown event.

In the case of server page inside the application you can also check if page exist like below before clearing a session value

```
System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.VirtualPathProvider.FileExists("~/SomePage.aspx");
```

Comment: Using `Session["filter"]=string.Empty` won't be effective as there are many pages and anyone of them can be a landing page.
Also, I cannot check if FileExists as I'm using Sitecore CMS so there won't be any physical aspx file.

Comment: Sorry I'm not in Sitecore person.  Are you using application state or user session? if you are using user session then it is unique to user  interaction.

Comment: Solved it by appending the value to Query string and checking for existence of Query string on page load.